# What's a word for someone you don't like?

Tags: synonyms

I'm looking for a noun for a person you don't like, but does not reveal any more information about that person besides disliking them/

Comment: It seems to me there are dozens of words that, realistically speaking, reveal nothing about the person other than your antipathy toward them.  "Shithead", for instance.

Answer (score 2):

You could use "enemy", "antagonist", "adversary", "foe", "rival", or "opposition".

Comment: This answer would be improved by providing an *explanation* of why these terms would be suitable, and what the differences between them are, supported by appropriate references and examples. I encourage you to review the [help] for guidance on writing good answers.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest:

**creep**:

*Someone who you dislike.* ***Longman Dictionary***

**Fink**:

*A person who you do not like.* ***Longman Dictionary***

But I prefer ***creep***:

"Leave me alone you creep." ***Merriam Webster***

"He was a real creep, he was always staring at me in the canteen." ***Cambridge advanced Learner's***

Answer (score 1):

You could use an *adjective* + the word *person*, as in:

"An unpleasant person"

"A disagreeable person"

As an alternative, you could use the latin term **persona non grata** (literally "disagreeable person").

Answer (score 0):

- [*Bête noire*](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=bete+noire): A detested person (WordWeb on line) - from French, but an English loan word.
- *anathema* (same definition, same source)

Answer (score 0):

**nemesis**

A bit harsh, but can be used humorously

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/nemesis?s=t

**thorn in my side**

Possibly the best option.

http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/thorn+in+side

Answer (score 0):

I've always thought degenerate was a great word and nobody ever uses. 
I.e. A real low life.

Or reprobate. Scoundrels good too.  They all mean the same pretty much.  For some reason my mind always goes straight to old timey.

"He's a bad egg that one. A good-for-nothing miscreant! One day that scurrilous naer-do-well in going to wind up in real hot soup. This ain't no line of bushwa I'm feeding you either."

Great habit too in real life. When the situation gets serious you really want a word like "Rapscallion" to be the the first thing out of your mouth.

Answer (score 0):

I'll go with ***putoff***.

> put someone off  (*also* put off someone): to cause someone to dislike someone [Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/put+off)
>
> *That dude is a putoff. For some reason I can't explain, I just can't stand/bear the sight of him.*

Answer (score -1):

[M-W](http://i.word.com/idictionary/antipathy) recognizes use of the word **antipathy** for:

> 3 : an object of aversion

Although phrases like he is my antipathy" seem to be very rare in English and probably a calque.